# copying files from etc ending with digit to test1 directory

Tags: linux, cp

I'm new to linux and as an exercice  I need to copy the "etc" files that end with a digit from  home directory to the test1 directory
(with one command).
I tried this but it dosn't work

```
find /etc -type f -iname "*[3-9]" -exec cp {} ../test1/ \;
```

Comment: Unclear. What do you mean by "etc files"? Files in `/etc/`? Then why your home directory? Do you need to consider subdiretories?

Comment: did my solution helped?

Answer (score 1):

this should work for your `home directory files ending with digit`

```
mv `ls . |grep -Eo  "^.*[0-9]$"` your-directory
```

lets says in the current directory you have some files like ofjweifhwef9 or kfhiofeh8 **( files ending with digit)**

so `ls` will list them.

this **grep expression** **"^.*[0-9]$"`** will find only files ending with digit. **( because in your home directory system  wont allow to have a file like this "/etc/somefile123")**

and then **mv will move those files to your-directory**

**note :- if grep cannot find the files ending with number you will see an error ofcourse because mv needs 2 operands but since it wasn't there so error.**

```
mv: missing destination file operand after './your-directory'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because `/etc` is a link in the system that you're using, and `find` doesn't seem to consider it a path until you add an extra `/` at the end. Try this instead:

```
find /etc/ -type f -iname "*[3-9]" -exec cp {} ../test1/ \;
```

Notice the `/etc/` instead of `/etc`. I get the same behavior on my Mac where /etc is a link to another directory.

Of course, also make sure that you have files which names end on a digit under the `/etc/` directory tree. I have none in my mac. You should get some files when you run:

```
find /etc/ -type f -iname "*[3-9]"
```

If you don't, you don't have any files to copy. You may also try: `find /etc/` to see all files under the directory tree.

Finally, you may want to add the option: `-depth 1` if you only want to copy the files in the `/etc/` directory, as opposed to all the files that match in the directory tree under `/etc/`.